# Geocoding search bar input into city with Nominatim and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

Is it possible to transform a search bar into a geocoder with Nominatim and Leaflet?

Using the search bar I would like to search for a city to view weather information and view it on the map.

In the image below you can see the app I am developing.

[image: Weather app]

In the example I am using geolocation, I would like to implement geocoding to search for a city.

I want to search for the city once to show both its weather conditions and its position on the map at the same time. So I want to turn the search bar into a geocode controller to show all the cities that contain the typed word.

Comment: You need a Leaflet plugin, for example *"Leaflet Control Geocoder"* - A simple geocoder for Leaflet that by default uses OSM/Nominatim, check these https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder and https://github.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder